# Negative functions and their anti-derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function with antiderivative
$$F(x)=\intop f(x) \mathrm{d}x,$$
where the constant of integration is zero. Does the following hold true: $$f(x)\leq0\;\forall\;x\in\mathbb{R}\Longleftrightarrow F(x)\leq 0\;\forall\;x?$$

Comment: No.  And it's quite easy to find a counterexample.

Comment: Keep in mind that $F(x)$ is only determined up to a constant.

Comment: When you say "ignore the constant of integration", does this mean you are choosing the specific constant $0$ each time? Even so, that doesn't really make sense..

Comment: @Tom : Yes. Edit has been made :-)

Comment: There exists no constant that can be referred to as **the** constant of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this does not hold true.

Let $\mathrm{f}(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then $\mathrm{F}(x)=k$, for some constant $k$, are all anti-derivatives of $\mathrm{f}$, i.e. $\mathrm{F}'(x)\equiv \mathrm{f}(x)$. In particular, $\mathrm{F}(x)=1$ is an anti-derivative of $\mathrm{f}$.

We have $\mathrm{f}(x) \le 0$ for all $x$ and yet $\mathrm{F}(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. If we ignore the constant of integration, does the statement then hold true?

Comment: @Chadman: How do you "ignore" the constant of integration?

Comment: @Frunobulax Question has been reworded. Constant equals zero.

Comment: @Chadman: Stil doesn't make sense.  $\frac x{x-1}$ and $\frac 1{x-1}$ both are antiderivatives of $-\frac1{(x-1)^2}$.  Which is the one with the constant being zero???

Comment: Or: $\arctan(x)$ and $-\operatorname{arccot}(x)$ are both antiderivatives of $\frac1{1+x^2}$.  Which is the one with the constant being zero???

Comment: @Frunobulax Come on, be nice. You made your point well. Don't stamp him into the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of on $\Bbb{R}$, here is an example on $(0, \infty)$, though you can consider a similar case for all of $\Bbb{R}$. Let $F(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ then $f(x) = F'(x) = - \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

In this context the data $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\; f\left(x\right)\leq0$ states exactly that every antiderivative $F$ of $f$ is non-increasing. It is enough to state this for only one of its antiderivatives because two antiderivatives will differ only a constant. It gives no information about the sign of antiderivatives.